# Is it possible to take values of an HTML5 SessionStorage and email it?

Tags: email, html

I'm creating an application with two pages (Page One, Page Two) that have radio buttons on them. The values are stored in sessionStorage and displayed to the user on Page 3. However, I want a Submit button that will take those values in sessionStorage and email it to me (I was planning to use PHP to process and send the email). Can someone help point me in the right direction on how to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a form with your submit button then you could have your javascript insert new inputs of `type="hidden"`, one for each key/value pair. These values will then be submitted with the form so you can process them just like any other POST parameter.